# Internal structure of executables compiled with Delphi

Tags: delphi, reverse-engineering

We are reversing Delphi internal structures, does anyone know of any good resource or other details about how Delphi executables are compiled and linked together and what is the layout of the various parts inside the final exe.

I am not looking for high level details like it has n sections.

I am looking for something (the following is 'made up') like section '.text' has 3 parts:

1. data (a)
2. pointers table (b)
3. code interleaved with data which can be identified by using mechanism (c)

etc,etc.

---

Ok, I am looking for references or knowledge about the structures. I already have the tools mentioned below, and a ton more to aid in reverse engineering this from scratch.

I should have mentioned that I know the resource layout as that is well documented. It's the internal compiled structures embedded in code and data sections I am after. (e.g. how RTTI info is compiled in, where is the mapping between event handlers and form resources, etc).

Comment: Have you tried opening the EXE in the delphi debugger (load process)? Just to see what you can see?

Answer (score 7):

Start with using existing tools like [IDR](http://kpnc.org/idr32/en/index.htm) (Interactive Delphi Reconstructor) and [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) (the Interactive Disassembler) and the already mentioned [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/).

I would also suggest compiling some simple executables and studying the disassembly of that.

Answer (score 5):

The most identifiable parts of a Delphi or C++ Builder executable are the resources.

They will contain a resource section named RCDATA.  This section contains the following:

- A section named DVCLAL, which identifies the compiler's SKU, such as Personal, Professional or Enterprise.
- A section named PACKAGEINFO, which contains a list of contained units and a flag for Delphi or C++ Builder
- Individual resources for each DFM.

On some settings, compressors like UPX may hide these resources, so you won't be able to see them unless you decompress the executable.

Answer (score 4):

It could be worthwhile to have a look at Jedi JCL. IIRC their traceback tools (jcldebug unit?) open binaries to recover debug info. It would at least teach the global structure of the file.

Some bits might be delphi version specific btw.

Downloading the evaluation version of PE-Explorer might be a good start too.

Comment: IIRC JclDebug works with linker map which it links in the executable as a resource - which would mean that it won't work if the map is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all types in a Delphi module (exe or dll) because they are always prepended with a pointer to the structure itself. You can create a small app and scan the exe to see for yourself how to get that information. With type information comes  good information where units are / where methods are etc etc.

Combine that information with the resources available (a good resource viewer can decode the binary resources in text for all forms /frames / datamodule ).

Now if you disassemble the application you can use the information from the resources / typeinfo to make sense of the assembly code found.